# Compiler Errors C#

Tags: c#, tcp, compiler-errors

```
        client.MessageRecieved += new EasyTCPClient.StringCarrier(this.client_MessageRecieved);
        client.OnConnectionLost += new EasyTCPClient.OnConnectionLostHandler(this.client_OnConnectionLost);
        client.Error += new EasyTCPClient.ErrorCarrier(this.client_Error);
```

I get the error messages:

> 'EasyTCP.EasyTCPClient.OnConnectionLost' is inaccessible due to its protection level
>   'EasyTCP.EasyTCPClient.MessageRecieved' is inaccessible due to its protection level
>   'EasyTCP.EasyTCPClient.Error' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I'm fairly new to C# so any help given would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
-Neel.

Comment: where are these libraries from?

Comment: they are quite poorly designed...

Comment: they're custom tcp framework.

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates you are trying to access a member with private or protected visibility, which is not allowed.

This library is not part of .net and so it's hard for me to work out how it is meant to be used. I can't immediately find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Those errors mean that those events are either `private` or `protected` modifiers on. Its hard to know how this library is designed.

Same with your `BabbelenControls`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the methods to `public` in order to be used from another class.

Comment: @Daniel - good point.  I assumed he had access to the source.

Comment: @Leons Even if the poster has access to the source, it clearly isn't meant to be used this way. The solution surely involves changes in the application code rather than in the library code.

Comment: how can I change it. Sorry I'm noobish about all this

Comment: @David - I agree.  My answer was based on the error message, but upon closer review it would appear that he is probably using a third party product (EasyTCP) in a manner that was not intended.